# RegEx and javascript replace not matching string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is code from my browser console which should work but strangly isn't:

```
> a = "13,50"
"13,50"
> regex = new RegExp(",50\\z")
/,50\z/
> a.replace(regex,"")
"13,50"
```

I'm testing the same thing in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and it's matching the ",50"

Any idea why this is not working??
Thanks

Comment: For testing JavaScript regex, you might want to use [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `\z` anchor in JavaScript. you can use `\b` or `$` instead.

`\z` anchor in most languages is used as an anchor for the end-of-string, and it was introduced in languages because `$` can match the end-of-line not end-of-string when multi-line mode is turned on.

So `$` and `\z` match exactly the same thing when you don't turn multi-line mode on.

Comment: Thanks! I was using  a RegEx reference for Ruby. Why can't it be the same in all languages?? Thanks anyway

Comment: @UriKlar You are welcome, JavaScript's regular expression flavor is a bit limited when compared to other more sophisticated flavors like PHP, Perl, .NET ... etc.

Comment: @UriKlar You can test your regular expressions at [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) and look at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for reference.

Comment: @UriKlar unfortunately, RegEx isn't overly standardized, but for the most part it's pretty good. The key is to read the documentation for the language you're using. Even if just briefly to see all of the extra features, and missing features, and different names for things